# The compiler is unable to type-check - SwiftUI

Tags: compiler-errors, swiftui, typechecking, compile-time-type-checking

I'm trying to get used to the MVVM-Pattern in swift. So I was coding around a bit and I get this error again and again:

> The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

I read a lot here, and i know that breaking up the code in smaller peaces would help - but with SwiftUI, I mean, thats pretty difficult, cause the code I wrote is just how it should be using SwiftUI (correct me if I'm wrong).

So, I'm pretty frustrated right now, trying to get this to work. Maybe anybody has an idea?

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

And the code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var modelPizza = PizzaModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        
            NavigationView {
                
                List(modelPizza.pizzas) { p in
                    
                    NavigationLink(
                            destination:
                                Text("Destination"),
                        label: {
                                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                    Text(p.name)
                                        .font(.title)
                                        
                                    HStack {
                                        Text(p.toping1)
                                            .italic()
                                        Text(p.toping2)
                                            .italic()
                                        Text(p.toping3)
                                            .italic()
                                    }
                                }
                                    
                            })
                    }.navigationTitle("Pizzas")
                Button(action: {
                    print("Hello")
                }, label:
                Text("Hello")
                )
            }
        
        }
        
    }


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Would love to hear from you - Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add code of PizzaModel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your Pizza struct conforms to Identifiable if you want to write it this way; otherwise, use `List(modelPizza.pizzas, id: \.self)` and have Pizza conform to Hashable.

I suggest adding a UUID property to pizza to conform to Identifiable.
The code below is an example that works on Swift 5, Xcode version 12.3:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var modelPizza = PizzaModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(modelPizza.pizzas) { pizza in
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Destination")) {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(pizza.name)
                            .font(.title)
                        
                        HStack {
                            Text(pizza.topping1)
                                .italic()
                            Text(pizza.topping2)
                                .italic()
                            Text(pizza.topping3)
                                .italic()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
 
    struct PizzaModel {
        var pizzas = [Pizza]()
        
        struct Pizza: Identifiable {
            var id = UUID()
            
            var name: String
            
            var topping1: String
            var topping2: String
            var topping3: String
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively:

```
struct PizzaModel {
    var pizzas = [Pizza]()
    
    struct Pizza: Hashable {
        var name: String
        
        var topping1: String
        var topping2: String
        var topping3: String
    }
}
```

and use `List(modelPizza.pizzas, id: \.self)`.

Comment: By the way, you definitely could break up your code into smaller pieces if you wanted. You could put the NavigationLink label into a separate computed property or another struct to simplify your code.

Comment: Yes i used UUID - i will try it with hashable. 

Comment: After i used Hashable - still didint work. I got the idea, that maybe my xcode is overloaded, but i dont know why. I mean, thats not a very long or complexe code...

Comment: That means that your code has something else wrong. The example above regarding the model works, so make sure you are putting hashable/identifiable in the right places and have the correct parameters for the list.  Swift often throws that type-check diagnostic when something is wrong but it can't determine what it is.

Comment: Thanks so much! I deleted the project and did it again, now it works.

Comment: Good! If you could accept my answer, that would be great. I did end up with a lot of these diagnostics especially working with ForEachs and Lists so I'm glad you were able to solve the issue.